# How to Implement Custom Windows Forms Designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form-designer

How can we implement Windows Forms Designer in a WinForms application ? Visual Studio uses System.ComponentModel.Design namespace to implement the Form Designer. How can we use this to implement a Form Designer in a WinForms application ? Is there any other library available for achieving the same ?

Comment: I found some exaples on CodeProject but that didnt work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something really interesting and helpful from CodePlex [here](http://mef.codeplex.com/). I read about this on [Brad Abram's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/04/13/managed-extensibility-framework-preview-5-released.aspx) Post. These includes many  examples on framework extensibility and Custom Windows Form Designer Interface is one of them.

**Link Txt 1: http://mef.codeplex.com/**

**Link Txt 2: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/04/13/managed-extensibility-framework-preview-5-released.aspx**

Thanks.