# vb.net get mouse selected control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating an windows form application. I have to do some actions after some of keyboard shortcuts is pressed. I have this part :

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Control & Keys.T Then
        'Wait till mouse clicks one of application controls
        'And get selected control information
    Else
        MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End If
End Function
```

Also, after this keyboard keys combination is pressed I have to get a control which is selected by mouse click. I am not able to make an event on every main form control (well, even if it would be possible I believe it's a stupid choice).

One of solution I have is Me.ActiveControl but it can't focus on labels and some other controls which can't be focused. So it's perhaps not the right choice.

Another solution which I found is global hooks but I can't understood how to use it. I'm asking your help and advices. If you have sample of global hooks or better solution how to get mouse clicked control share it :) Any help is appreciated, feel free to write your opinion :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want in my windows form press ctrl + t keyboard combination then press on control with mouse and get that user selected control. Why I am doing this? Because I need to get any of user selected control on application.

Comment: Why do you need to select a control in run time? What will you do with it?

Comment: Are you trying to [Implement Custom Windows Forms Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743988/how-to-implement-custom-windows-forms-designer)?

Comment: I need to select a control in run time because that I will change it later (well, I will change it some of properties).

Comment: So you are in fact trying to implement a custom winforms designer. If so, please have a look at the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is backwards for Windows programming.

The correct approach is to check in the control's click event if Ctrl+T is being pressed and respond accordingly.

1. Import the Win API 'GetKeyState'
2. Use 'GetKeyState' to check if the Ctrl Key and the T key are down.

See the [PInvoke page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeystate) for more information.

The correct way to [handle a click event for all controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form) is simply to add a central click event handler for all controls placing your key down logic in that handler.

These are advanced techniques which require more in depth knowledge of WinForms.

Comment: So `PInvoke` is a step forward you think? :)